# Conditional inserts and rollback

Tags: oracle, insert

I have three insert statements A,b and C which are to be executed in sequence. If A fails, then C has to fail and vice-versa. How to handle this situation?

Comment: I have rephrased your requirement. Kindly confirm the below. "Execute A. Irrespective of whether A failed or succeeded execute B. Irrespective of whether B failed or succeeded execute C only when A succeeded. If C fails, ensure that A is also failed or rolled back".

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding why it's important for them to be executed in sequence if B can be the only one that successfully runs.

Comment: @ArtBajji: yes you got it right. Actually this was asked by one of the interviewer.

Answer (score 0):

Table creation:

```
drop table mytab;
create table mytab(v varchar2(10));
```

Procedure with Autonomous Transaction: Autonomous transaction allows nested transaction to be committed even if the outer transaction is rolled back.

```
create or replace procedure sp_tranB as
pragma autonomous_transaction;--runs as a separate transaction and commits irrespective of outer transaction
begin
    insert into mytab values('Insert B');
    commit;
exception when others
          then null;
end;
```

Scenario: All inserts succeed.

```
declare
    a_status number;
begin
    a_status := 0;
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert A');
        --do not commit here. This allows rollback if C fails.
    exception when others
              then a_status := 1;
    end;

    begin
        sp_tranB;
    end;

    if a_status = 0 then
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert C');
        commit;
    exception when others
              then rollback;
    end;
    end if;

end;

select * from mytab;
```

output:

```
V
Insert A
Insert B
Insert C

truncate table mytab;
```

Scenario: A fails and prevents C

```
declare
    a_status number;
begin
    a_status := 0;
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert A too large');--A fails
        --do not commit here. This allows rollback if C fails.
    exception when others
              then a_status := 1;
    end;

    begin
        sp_tranB;
    end;

    if a_status = 0 then--C must not execute as A fails
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert C');
        commit;
    exception when others
              then rollback;
    end;
    end if;

end;

select * from mytab;
```

Output:

```
V
Insert B

truncate table mytab;
```

Scenario: C fails and rollback A

```
declare
    a_status number;
begin
    a_status := 0;
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert A');
        --do not commit here. This allows rollback if C fails.
    exception when others
              then a_status := 1;
    end;

    begin
        sp_tranB;
    end;

    if a_status = 0 then
    begin
        insert into mytab values('Insert C too large');--C fail and....
        commit;
    exception when others
              then rollback;
              --...rollsback A
    end;
    end if;

end;

select * from mytab;
```

Output:

```
V
Insert B
```

Note: It is not advisable to suppress exceptions with "WHEN OTHERS NULL;". Do not use it in your applications. It is used here only to demonstrate the feature of autonomous transactions for this specific requirement.